# bind rails app on the IP provided by the host with 3000 port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, port

I am running the rails app on VPS server provided by my host.

I need to run the same local app to the IP provided by them.

For eg `myip:3000`

Is it possible to do this, the IP provided by the host is a public/global IP.

How can I do this? Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: you can use `-b` option to run on your ip address
for example `rails s - b 111.222.333.444 -p 3000`

Comment: Oh yes, I was forgetting to add -b in the command. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

After the release of `Rails 4.2` the you cannot access the development mode rails server from another computer/virtual machine (remote access). So you need to bind the server to the `ip`. You can do it by:

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

> 0.0.0.0 (means listen on all interfaces)

If you want to do it permanently you can do it by modifying the `config/boot.rb` like this:

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'rails/commands/server'

module Rails  
  class Server
    alias :default_options_bk :default_options
    def default_options
      default_options_bk.merge!(Host: '0.0.0.0')
    end
  end
end
```

**Source:** https://fullstacknotes.com/make-rails-4-2-listen-to-all-interface/